# sliding window using strides function producing matrix with unknown numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, stride

where these new numbers are coming from?

```
a=np.arange(21)

np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a,(12,3),strides=(8,4))
```

[image]

Comment: ```np.arange``` will produce 64 bit integers. setting a stride to ```4``` is only valid for 32 bit dtypes.

Comment: That's a dange of `as_strided`.  If you don't get the strides and shape right, you can sample bytes outside the array's data buffer.  Shape should be (10,3).